# how to properly create a case statement to map an alias to a value

Tags: bash, shell, unix, case

I'm trying to figure out create this `case` statement. What I am trying to do is map my input parameter `$1` which has to be one of the 3 options and then map to the hostname. My command is failing. How do I assign my variable to value?  What is the best way to do this?

Execute:

```
./test.sh cluster1
```

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
ENDPOINT="$1"
SCH="$2"

case $ENDPOINT in
        "cluster1") $HOST="myhost1.abcde.us-west-1.amazonaws.com";;
        "cluster2") $HOST="myhost2.abcde.us-west-1.amazonaws.com";;
        "cluster3") $HOST="myhost3.abcde.us-west-1.amazonaws.com";;
esac

psql $HOST -U myuser -d $SCH -p 5439 << EOF
```

Getting the error:

```
/test.sh: line 18: =myhost1.abcde.us-west-1.amazonaws.com: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would work if you remove the `$` before `HOST` variable while making an assignment.

```
#!/bin/bash
ENDPOINT="$1"
SCH="$2"

case $ENDPOINT in
        "cluster1") HOST="myhost1.abcde.us-west-1.amazonaws.com";;
        "cluster2") HOST="myhost2.abcde.us-west-1.amazonaws.com";;
        "cluster3") HOST="myhost3.abcde.us-west-1.amazonaws.com";;
esac

psql "$HOST" -U myuser -d "$SCH" -p 5439 << EOF
```

Also try using getopts for better scalability.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example using `getopts`?

Comment: @noober Absolutely! [This](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) is a great place to start! `:)`

Answer (score -2):

You should change your case statement like this:

```
HOST=$(case $ENDPOINT in
    "cluster1") echo "myhost1.abcde.us-west-1.amazonaws.com";;
    "cluster2") echo "myhost2.abcde.us-west-1.amazonaws.com";;
    "cluster3") echo "myhost3.abcde.us-west-1.amazonaws.com";;
esac)
```

Can't test right now, let me know if it works.

Comment: No reason for a subshell here.